# How can I upgrade my Mac's apache to the latest version?

Tags: macos, apache

I can't figure out where my Mac's apache installation files are (source files).

Doing which apachectl or which ab just shows me /usr/sbin/ and not the original sources, do they even exist on the system or is it just the compiled binaries?

The end goal for me is to upgrade from 2.2.2 that I have no to the latest version.

How can I do this?  or can I blow out what I have now and install it via homebrew.

Comment: This question would better be answered on http://apple.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Youll find the headers in `/usr/include/apache2`. However i wouldnt upgrade they systems apache. I would use Homebrew, MacPorts, Fink, or a manual installation. This way it doesnt get blown away by a system update or break a dependency somewhere. Its probably unlikely either of those would happen, but you never know 100%.

Comment: /usr/include/apache2 folder doesn't exist on MBP (2010 version).

Comment: What version of OS X are you running? Ive checked on Snow Leopard and Lion and it exists...

Comment: I have lion, i'm not on the computer now but was yesterday and I couldn't find that darn folder, i'll check again.